# bulk insert into Cassandra UDT using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark to bulk insert Facebook data for analysis I have *comment* as a UDT in cassandra . the a table *fbpost* that has set of *comments* as a column
Below is the schema

```
CREATE TYPE analytics.comment (
commentid text,
commenttext varchar,
username text,
commentdatetime timestamp );

CREATE TABLE analytics.posts (
postid text,
username text,
comments set<frozen<comment>>,
datetime timestamp,
posttext varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (datetime, username)
```

from the spark job written in Java I am creating a JavaRDD(of type FBposts) which i need to save in the Cassandra table. I have pojos for both FBpost and Comments .

```
 javaFunctions(fbPostFromMysql).writerBuilder("analytics", "posts", fbPostWriter).saveToCassandra();
```

May be I am not doing the **mapping for my Java  comment pojo to UDTValue correctly** which is why i am getting  TypeConversionException below is the stacktrace

```
localhoatastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object Comment [commentId=642528915901340_642701759217389, commenttext=Prix, username=Angel Nannousa, commentdatetime=2016-07-0 
class com.prophecy.spark.cassandra.model.Comment to com.datastax.driver.core.UDTValue
```

Here is the java code for rowwriter

```
public class FbPostRowWriter implements RowWriter<FbPost> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static RowWriter<FbPost> writer = new FbPostRowWriter();

// Factory
public static class FbPostRowWriterFactory implements RowWriterFactory<FbPost>, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public RowWriter<FbPost> rowWriter(TableDef tableDef, IndexedSeq<ColumnRef> arg1) {
        return writer;
    }
}

@Override
public Seq<String> columnNames() {      
    return scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(FbPost.columns()).toList();
}

@Override
public void readColumnValues(FbPost summary, Object[] buffer) {
    buffer[0] = summary.getPostId();
    buffer[1] = summary.getUsername();
    buffer[3] = summary.getDatetime();
    buffer[4] = summary.getPosttext();  
    buffer[2] = summary.getComments();
    }
}
```

Please suggest How do I map set of Comment to be able to insert data in UDT column